# Spring-data @Query annotation and interface

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

**Spring-data-mongodb 1.1.2-Released (Spring-data-common-core 1.4.1.Released)**

I am having some trouble with using the @Query annotation with interface.  For example, if I have the following interface defined:

```
public interface Person {
    String getName();
    Integer getAge();
}
```

and the following Repository defined:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

    @Query(value="{ 'name': ?0}")
    List<Person> findPeople(String name);
}
```

I get the following exception when trying to query:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No property name found on com.abc.People!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getPath(QueryMapper.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getTargetProperty(QueryMapper.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$Execution.readCollection(AbstractMongoQuery.java:123)
```

This exception does not occur if my @Query is updated to:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    @Query(value="{ 'abcd': ?0}")
    List<Person> findPeople(String name);
}
```

This also does not occur if I remove the getName() function from the interface.

Has anyone encountered this issue and can tell me what I am doing wrong or if this is an known issue?  I will open an JIRA in Spring-data project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are stumbling over [this one](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-311). This has been fixed in the release announced [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2013/04/25/spring-data-arora-sr1-released/). You should see this working by upgrading to Spring Data MongoDB 1.2.1 (which pulls in Spring Data Commons 1.5.1 transitively).